# Which components installed with MS Visual Studio 2012/2013 are unnecessary?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying out MS Visual Studio 2012. I just need to write non-GUI non-Windows-specific C++ code (actually I'm going to use CUDA, but never mind that). So, surely I don't need, what is it, upwards of 5GB of files? How can I remove some/most of them, while keeping the core functionality?

Of course I don't mean the components you can tell the installer to skip, but rather those that it forces you to accept without telling you anything about them. Do I have to have Sliverlight? .Net 4.5.x? Multiple Windows Dev Kits? MS SQL Server? etc.

Comment: Do you not have 5GB of free disk space?

Comment: @jalf: Not for MSVS I don't...

Comment: It's unsafe to remove anything without using the installer.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't see the point of debating whether you need actually need a component if the installer doesn't give you an option to skip said component. You must install it, and that's the end of the story.

Comment: @Praetorian: I'm not debating whether I must install things, I'm asking whether I can remove some of them after installation. If your answer is "No, anything you remove will prevent VS 2012 from working", then just say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the installation of Visual Studio you have the option to exclude various components.  Excluding the Web Projects, Office components, etc ...  will remove a significant chunk of the disk space requirements.

Other than that there is not much to do.  Deleting random files isn't an answer and in general outside of the initial installation there is no supported way to remove components

**EDIT**

Silverlight I'm skeptical needs to be there for non-Silverlight developement.  Probably the same for the Windows Dev Kits but it's possible they're installing a COM component that Visual Studio uses.  .Net and MS SQL are definitely required (the latter for C++ development in particular).

The universal truth though is that trying to run Visual Studio after force uninstalling these components is not a supported operation.  It is not tested and will almost certainly lead to unexpected behavior.